# Generate New Tabs

Tags: excel

There is a syntax that we use in our office that autogenerate reports from Excel into .pdfs for all the schools in our district.  My code:

```
Function Create_PDF(Myvar As Object, FixedFilePathName As String, _
                    OverwriteIfFileExist As Boolean, OpenPDFAfterPublish As Boolean) As String
    Dim FileFormatstr As String
    Dim FName As Variant

'Test If the Microsoft Add-in is installed
If Dir(Environ("commonprogramfiles") & "\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE" _
     & Format(Val(Application.Version), "00") & "\EXP_PDF.DLL") <> "" Then

    If FixedFilePathName = "" Then
        'Open the GetSaveAsFilename dialog to enter a file name for the pdf
        FileFormatstr = "PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf"
        FName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("", filefilter:=FileFormatstr, _
                                              Title:="Create PDF")

        'If you cancel this dialog Exit the function
        If FName = False Then Exit Function
    Else
        FName = FixedFilePathName
    End If

    'If OverwriteIfFileExist = False we test if the PDF
    'already exist in the folder and Exit the function if that is True
    If OverwriteIfFileExist = False Then
        If Dir(FName) <> "" Then Exit Function
    End If

    'Now the file name is correct we Publish to PDF
    On Error Resume Next
    Myvar.ExportAsFixedFormat _
            Type:=xlTypePDF, _
            FileName:=FName, _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
            IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
            OpenAfterPublish:=OpenPDFAfterPublish
    On Error GoTo 0

    'If Publish is Ok the function will return the file name
    If Dir(FName) <> "" Then Create_PDF = FName
End If

End Function
Sub SaveAllYourReports()

Dim MyFolder As String
Dim MyFile As String
Dim PDFname As String
Dim FileName As String

On Error Resume Next
MyFolder = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop") & Application.PathSeparator & "PDF Reports"
MkDir MyFolder
On Error GoTo 0

For Each r In ActiveSheet.Range("Schools")

   ActiveSheet.Range("SelectedSchool").Value = r.Value
   If r.Value <> 0 Then

    PDFname = r.Value
    MyFile = MyFolder & Application.PathSeparator & PDFname
    FileName = Create_PDF(ActiveSheet.Range("ReportArea"), MyFile, True, False)
    End If

    Next r
    ActiveSheet.Range("SelectedSchool").Value = ActiveSheet.Range("FirstSchool").Value
End Sub
```

Is there a way/how to modify our existing code so that instead of creating .pdfs, it creates unique tabs in an Excel spreadsheet, where each tab represents a school?

Answer (score 0):

Use .Add in the workbook's Sheets collection.  See:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839847.aspx